# can't connect to postgres in ipv6 using docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, networking, ubuntu-20.04, netplan

My scenario is the following: I have a postgres 12 installed on ubuntu 20.04 server and a docker container running in another host with ipv6 enabled.

I can't reach postgres server from inside docker container using ipv6.

these commands works from within the container:

```
$ ping POSTGRES_SERVER_IPv4
$ ping POSTGRES_SERVER_IPv6
$ telnet POSTGRES_SERVER_IPv4 5432
```

but this does not work from inside the container (but it works from the docker host):

```
$ telnet POSTGRES_SERVER_IPv6 5432
```

i've already set listen_address = '*' and "host all all md5" in postgres pg_hba.conf.

**EDIT:**

i've realized that my network adapter is using two IPv6, the static one that I defined in netplan and another one that is within my network range, but I didn't assigned it.

Comment: Can you reach the postgres server from another (non-docker) machine?

Comment: "Before you can use IPv6 in Docker containers or swarm services, you need to enable IPv6 support in the Docker daemon." ... https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/

Comment: Yes i can @Turing85.

Comment: It is already enabled @MarcSances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your netplan configuration, try to add:

accept-ra: no

example:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens192:
      accept-ra: no
      addresses: ...
```

Comment: thanks, it solved. apparently my adapter was getting another ipv6 from my RA, but the curious thing is that the problem was only ocurring inside docker container or using putty (ssh).